# getElementById setting the id dynamically getting undefined reference

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, getelementbyid

I want to access the value of a table cell using the id.  It works when I use this statement:

```
var temp = document.getElementById('txtClassCode-241').value;
```

However, when I try to use a value of the id that is dynamically set, I get a syntax error saying it is a null or undefined reference;

```
var temp = document.getElementById("'txtClassCode-" + myDynamicId + "'").value;
```

Comment: You're using single quotes as part of your generated ID value, that's why it's failing. Try var temp = document.getElementById('txtClassCode-' + myDynamicId.toString()).value;

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up single quotes and double quotes.

You only need one or the other.

My preference is single quotes:

```
var temp = document.getElementById('txtClassCode-' + myDynamicId).value;
```